# How to display a time picker?

Tags: datepicker, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need display a time picker in sencha touch, in a similar way of `xtype: 'datepickerfield'`, any idea how to do it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [SenchaTouch-v2-Datetimepicker](https://github.com/tomalex0/SenchaTouch-v2-Datetimepicker)

It is a bit buggy, but mostly works. A drawback is the license is not set. Guess GPL, but he don't answer on the email about it...

Cheers, Oleg

Answer (score 2):

Sencha Market gives an extension for datetimepicker..Have not tried it but I hope it is useful for you

https://market.sencha.com/users/21/extensions/43

Comment: This is the same project I have referenced above. Author tomalex or Thomas Alexander :)

Comment: Sorry didn't know i found this while i was browsing in sencha market